# Is it possible to wildcard a filename string to password protect a file with htaccess?

Tags: string, .htaccess, passwords

Example: `wp_file*.log` -- what that should do is to password protect every file whose filename start with wp_file and ends with .log -- for example `wp_file-22.log` and `wp_file_randomfile.log`.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would make this, is by adding a rewrite rule for those files, redirect to some PHP file with the origional request in the GET. The PHP file can than show a password box and eventually the content of the log file once logged in.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule wp_file(.*)\.log /somePHPfile.php?logFile=wp_file$1 [L]
```

(not tested)

If you dont need access to the log files via your website (but use e.g. ftp), than you can rewrite the requests to those files to another page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule wp_file(.*)\.log /index.php [L]
```